# Tried to use a sub() on a single string and it just changes the first character desired, not all the occurrences on the string

Tags: r, string

I'm fairly new on the language and decided to give me a little exercise. I tried to change the commas in this expression

```
0,869*(100/3)+0,791*(100/3)+0,757*(100/3)+0,723*0+0,544*0+0,237*100
```

for dots.

But when i try to use the sub() function, it just changes the first comma, not the others. Could someone explain to me why this happens? Sorry if it's an easy question, i tried to search and found nothing. Here's the code:

```
sub(",",".","0,869*(100/3)+0,791*(100/3)+0,757*(100/3)+0,723*0+0,544*0+0,237*100")
```

Comment: Try `gsub` instead of `sub`. From `?sub` - "sub and gsub perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively."

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the documentation for sub it says that it replaces only the first instance - use `gsub` or `str_replace_all` in stringr :)

```
string <- "0,869*(100/3)+0,791*(100/3)+0,757*(100/3)+0,723*0+0,544*0+0,237*100"

sub(",",".",string)
[1] "0.869*(100/3)+0,791*(100/3)+0,757*(100/3)+0,723*0+0,544*0+0,237*100"

gsub(",",".",string)
[1] "0.869*(100/3)+0.791*(100/3)+0.757*(100/3)+0.723*0+0.544*0+0.237*100"

stringr::str_replace_all(string, ",",".")
[1] "0.869*(100/3)+0.791*(100/3)+0.757*(100/3)+0.723*0+0.544*0+0.237*100"
```

Comment: Please, provide simple examples.